# Find the number of tangent lines to a curve

Tags: tangent-line

The number of tangent to curve
$$y^2 - 2x^3 - 4y + 8 = 0$$ that passes through $(1,2)$

My work 
Assuming tangent touch the curve at$(x_1,y_1)$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3x^2}{(y - 2)} $$
$$\frac{2 - y_1}{1- x_1}=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{3x_1^2}{(y_1 - 2)}$$, 
I should need one more equation. How I will get that?

Comment: Is the point (1,2) on the curve?

Comment: No, tangent possess through it

Comment: tangent on curve passs through this point, means it satisfies equation of tangent not curve

Comment: Sorry my bad, I misinterpreted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-multiply and you will have:

$$(2-y_1)(y_1 - 2) = 3x_1^2(1-x_1) \implies -y^2 + 4y_1 -4 = 3x_1^2 - 3x_1^3$$

Now substitute $y_1^2 - 2x_1^3 - 4y_1 + 8 =0$ and eventually you will get:

$$-2x_1^3 + 4 = 3x_1^2 - 3x_1^3 \implies x_1^3 - 3x_1^2 + 4 = (x_1-2)^2(x_1+1) = 0$$

But it's fairly easy to see that $x=-1$ doesn't give solutions and you will get 2 distinct solutions from $x=2$